# Trying to export an oracle apex application from sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have been locked out of my apex workspace and there seems to be no hope but i still do have my database connection in sqldeveloper and i want my apex application. Normally i know you got to the **Application Express** under the db connection menu as seen here:

[image]

but apparaently for some reason i am not seeing **Application Express** under the menu and i am connected to the db as a sysdba. How can i activate this feature? or how do i get it to show up?
Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: In what way are you locked out of the application?

If your account has been locked due to failed login attempts, you can unlock your user via the APEX_050100 user in your database.

Try unlocking your user in the wwv_flow_fnd_user table and update your password.

    update APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_FND_USER
    set web_password = <password>
    where user_name = <username>;

Comment: Hi Basudev, did you still need help or did Jeff's answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Don't login AS SYSDBA - it totally changes the way the data dictionary appears for your session. Try again as SYSTEM or the schema owner.

You could also try the 'apex export' command in SQLcl, a command line, interactive version of SQL Developer. There should be a SQL exe in your SQL Developer bin folder. You start it just like you would SQLPlus.

```
SQLcl: Release 19.2.1 Production on Fri Apr 17 11:25:40 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Username? (''?) hr
Password? (**********?) ******
Last Successful login time: Fri Apr 17 2020 11:25:44 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0


SQL> help apex
APEX
---------

apex - Lists Application Express Applications
apex export <app id> - Exports the application which could be combined with spool for writing to a file
SQL>
```

Comment: Great to hear @BasudevSingh - welcome to the Oracle community on StackOverflow!